# Can you call getRecord or @wire from child component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire, parent-to-child

I'm trying to make a basic with the @wire method on the contact record to pull in a phone number. But the error I keep getting is

- Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined on **c:ParentElement**
- Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined on **c:ChildElement**

Anyone ever had this problem before? I have a feeling it has to do with the execution order of the LWC and the data not getting in there, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing that issue.

### Parent html

```
<template if:true={objectApiName}>
            Contact
            <c-child-element get-object-from-parent={objectApiName} get-record-id-from-parent={recordId}></c-child-element>
</template>
```

### Parent js

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';


export default class ParentElement extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName; // contact object

    @api recordId; //contact record id
```

### Child html

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-align_center">
        Record Id : {getRecordIdFromParent}
    </div>
    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-align_center">
        Object Name : {getObjectFromParent}
    </div>
    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-align_center">
        ContactPhone : {contactPhone}
    </div>

</lightning-card>
```

### Child JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';


export default class ChildElement extends LightningElement {
    @api getRecordIdFromParent;
    @api getObjectFromParent;
    @api contactPhone;


    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$getRecordIdFromParent', fields:['Contact.Phone']})
    contact;


    get contactPhone() {
        return this.contact.data.fields.Phone.value;
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I may have figured it out using <template if:true = {contact.data}> ...... </template> seems like it was the issue with trying to load the Record Id: Object Name: in the HTML before it got into the JS of the child element?

Comment: Any insight into why this works, would be helpful. Still not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wire methods load their data asynchronously, so you'll go at least one `render()` cycle before the data is available. You do need to check for null values to avoid this error.

There's a handy [utility method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value) to avoid having to check for null values, etc:

```
import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CONTACTPHONEFIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Phone';
```

...

```
get contactPhone() {
    return getFieldValue(this.contact.data, CONTACTPHONEFIELD);
}
```